# Getting facebook likes count via javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have the following script:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'app_id_of_one_of_my_apps',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.7'
    });

    FB.api("/{numerical_profile_id}/likes",
    function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    });


  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>
```

All I get is error `An access token is required to request this resource`

How do I securely get Facebook fanpage likes count via javascript? Or do I need to make a PHP script that will do it for me?

Comment: if you want to fetch information for a particular user you need that user's permission. The access_token represents that the user gave permission to your site to do so.

Comment: On my site, i want to show Like count of my fanpage. Like "Like" button.

Comment: You either need to make the user login, so that you can use their user access token – or you need to do it on the server side, so that you can use your app or a page token. (Those two should never be exposed in client-side code.) Plus, doing it on the server side allows you to implement some basic form of caching, so that you don’t run into the API rate limits so easily.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the API to get the fan count:

```
/{page-id}?fields=fan_count
```

...or with the JavaScript SDK:

```
FB.api('/{page-id}', {fields: 'fan_count'}, (response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

You can use an App Token if the page is not restricted by age or location, but you MUST use the Token server side. Tokens are always meant to be kept secret. No login is needed for the App Token, it is just a combination of App ID and App Secret (ID|Secret) and it is permanent.

More information about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Side note: You should do that API call server side anyway and cache the result in your database, or you will definitely hit the API limit if you get a lot of users/hits.

Comment: Selected best answer for mentioning age/location restriction (which seem to be my problem) and ID|Secret combination!